# c# проблема с {} при сохранении в файл

Tags: c#

Есть стока сохраняю ее в csv в UTF8 все работает без проблем.
Если в этой строке появляются скобки отказывается сохранять и вылетает в ошибку.
Помогите решить проблему и обьясните почему оно так...
на форме 1 текстбокс и кнопка в текстбоксе строка: {total.text} траляляляля

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace пппппппппп
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            save.Filter = "Text documents (.csv)|*.csv";

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(save.FileName);

                foreach (var item in textBox1.Lines)
                    w.WriteLine(item.ToString(), (Encoding.UTF8));

                w.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: какие скобки? какая ошибка?

Comment: {total.text} траляляляля

Comment: "и вылетает в ошибку" - в секретную?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/un9dyz

Comment: не настолько продвинут чтоб понимать какими бывают ошибки сделал  скрин

Comment: Ошибки бывают такими, что у них есть тип, сообщение и stack trace. Всю эту информацию надо добавить в вопрос.

Comment: Кодировку можно задать в конструкторе, при создании стримрайтера.

Comment: Можно на примере моего кода показать как это сделать?

Comment: Я пару дней в теме, простые вещи для меня сложные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте более современное файловое API.

```csharp
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.Filter = "Text documents (.csv)|*.csv";

    if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(save.FileName, textBox1.Lines);
    }
}
```

**UTF-8** здесь по умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо работает!